# Longest Common SubString, BigQuery, SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, lcs

Given I have two a Table with Two string columns:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| John likes to go jumpping | Max likes swimming but he also likes to go jummping |
| John is cool | max is smart |
| John | max |

In Big-query SQL How can I find the longest common substring? such that I get

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John likes to go jumping | Max likes swimming but he also likes to go jumping | likes to go jumping |
| John is cool | max is smart | is |
| John | max | null |

Comment: If only there were articles and books that talked about such an unusual and rare problem...

Comment: Very painfully.  This is not a very SQLish operation.

Comment: I was being flip before, but here is why this is a bad question for SO and I'm going to vote to close.  First there is a bad design choice to implement this in SQL (as @GordonLinoff pointed out).   Second this site is not about solve the whole problem it is about answer a question or problem with existing code.  If you want the whole problem solved hire a consulting firm.  (or a freelance programmer)

Comment: while your comments in general and formally correct - what we have here is: same (literally same) but differently worded "problems with existing code" are being asked and answered here again and again thousand+ times without any attempts from those who ask and those who answers to actually do some extra work and point to already existing answers. This is soo boring! But when someone asks really interesting and challenging question - it becomes not qualified and not SQL'ish! :o(

Answer (score 1):

Try below very much SQL'ish approach

```
select A, B, 
  (
    select string_agg(word, ' ' order by a_pos) phrase 
    from unnest(split(A, ' ')) word with offset a_pos
    join unnest(split(B, ' ')) word with offset b_pos
    using(word)
    group by b_pos - a_pos
    order by length(phrase) desc
    limit 1
  ) as C
from `project.dataset.table`
```

when applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]

Obviously your example is very simple, so in real use case you might need to adjust above to reflect reality

Also, note: there are many other options/approaches for your problem that SO has already multiple answers for, including mine - for text similarity mostly based on using JS UDF and levenshtein distance or similar algorithms

Answer (score 1):

This probably is not a problem for your SQL to solve (it is though very simple to solve via any scripting language). However, BigQuery does support JS based UDFs, which usually come in handy to solve such problems.

Here is an option (*which at its core is not SQL*) that you can take in BigQuery:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION lcsub(a string, b string)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  a = a.split(' ');
  b = b.split(' ');
  let la = a.length;
  let lb = b.length;
  let output = [];
  for (var i=0; i<la; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<lb; j++){
        if (a[i] == b[j]){
            let u = [b[j]]
            let aidx = i;
            for (var k = j+1; k<lb; k++){
               u.push(b[k]);
               if (u.join(' ') == a.slice(i, aidx +1+1).join(' ')){
                  if (u.length >= output.length){
                    output = u;
                  }
               }
               else {
                  u.pop();
                  if (u.length >= output.length){
                    output = u;
                  }
                  break;
               }
                aidx += 1;
                if (aidx > la -1){
                  break
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
  return output.join(' ')

""";

select A, B, lcsub(A, B) as C from dataset.table
```